# Precise form of the mean motion theorem

Tags: reference-request, trigonometric-polynomials, celestial-mechanics

Consider an exponential polynomial
$$f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\exp(i\lambda_kt),$$
where $a_k$ are complex and $\lambda_k, t$ real. The usual form of the Mean Motion Theorem says that the limit
$$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{\arg f(t)}{t}$$
exists. (If $f$ has real zeros one defines $\arg f$ by bypassing them along small
half-circles in the upper half-plane).

All books that I know mention that this was conjectured by Lagrange, and proved by 
P. Bohl for $n=3$ and by B. Jessen and H. Tornehave (1945) in general, after earlier incomplete proofs by H. Weyl and P. Hartman. However in the paper of Bohl, a much more subtle question is actually studied, namely whether we have
$$\arg f(t)=ct+O(1).$$
He shows that for $n=3$ this is sometimes the case, sometimes not, and gives an
exact condition in terms of $a_k,\lambda_k$. My question is:

> Has anyone ever continued this line of inquiery? Can
>   $$\arg f(t)=ct+o(t)$$
>   be improved: a) in general, b) under some additional conditions on $a_k,\lambda_k$?

Of course one such condition is known since Lagrange: if $|a_1|>\sum_{k=2}^n|a_k|$, then the error term is $O(1)$.

Ref. P. Bohl, "[Über ein in der Theorie der säkularen Störungen vorkommendes Problem](https://eudml.org/doc/149304)", J. reine angew Math. 135 (1909) 189-283. There is a Russian translation
in P. Bohl, Collected Works, Riga, Znanie, 1974.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: Thanks for the editing. I am unable to remember how to type foreign language accents and umlauts in html. And Math Jack only handles the formulas.

Comment: Should the formula be $\sum a_k \exp(i \lambda_k t)$? (This differs from the stated formula by an $i$ in the argument of $\exp$.)

Comment: @David E Speyer: Yes, thanks. I corrected.

Comment: Something with the last sentence is wrong because $|a_1| > \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_k|$ makes no sense.

Comment: I don't think the result can be improved in general except for the Lagrangian case. Already for $N=2$ it was shown by Bernstein that in "most cases" the remainder is generally unbouded. There is a fairly extensive review by Jessen and Tornehave that you are probably aware of, but I'm not sure if they address your question there.

Comment: @Icv: Bohl's result shows that for n=3
 it can be improved in cases, different from Lagrange's case. Look in Bohl's paper!