# Are we able to estimate the fraction of the domain where $\cos (ax)+2\cos (b x)$ with $\frac ab \notin\mathbb{Q}$ is positive?

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, irrational-numbers, trigonometric-polynomials

We know that the two functions $\{\;\cos (ax),\;2\cos (b x)\;\}$ where $\frac ab \notin \mathbb{Q}$ are independently positive (and negative) over $\frac 12$ of the domain.

Is it possible to estimate the fraction of the domain in which $\;\cos (ax)+2\cos (b x) \;$ is positive (in this case, the function is not periodic)?

In other words, can we estimate
$$ \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac 1m  \int_{0}^{m} \Big(\cos (ax)+2\cos (b x) >0\Big) \,dx?$$

Any hints and comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found "the ratio of the domain" confusing; I think you meant something like "the fraction of the domain".  I have edited accordingly, hopefully without changing the meaning.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, that is true, thanks.

Comment: Interesting question. If the amplitudes were equal, i.e. the function was $\cos(ax)+\cos(bx)$, it could be rewritten as a product $2\cos(Ax)\cos(Bx)$ with $A=(a+b)/2$, $B=(a-b)/2$, and one would only have to worry about the signs of the two cosines. But with the different amplitudes it "beats" me. (Pun intended, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics) )

Comment: I guess the answer is of the form “mumble ergodic mumble fraction of $(u,v) \in (\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z})^2$ such that $\cos(u) + 2\cos(v) > 0$, which is equal to mumble”, but I don't know the magic words with which to replace the first two “mumble” and I don't have the patience to compute the value of the last “mumble”. 

Comment: PS: The mean motion theorem and the references given in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278996/precise-form-of-the-mean-motion-theorem) is relevant to a closely related question (computing the number of zeros of this function in a given interval).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since $a,b$ are incommensurable, $(ax,bx)$ is asymptotically equidistributed
in the torus $({\bf R} / 2\pi{\bf Z})^2$.
[One proof is via a continuous version of Weyl's equidistribution criterion:
for any integers $r,s$ with $(r,s) \neq (0,0)$ we have
$$
\frac1m \int_0^m e^{i(rax+sbx)}\, dx = O_{r,s}(1/m) \to 0
$$
as $m \to \infty$.]  Therefore $\{x > 0 \mid \cos ax + 2 \cos bx > 0 \}$
has the same density in the positive reals as
$\{ (\theta,\phi) \in ({\bf R} / 2\pi{\bf Z})^2 \mid 
 \cos \theta + 2 \cos \phi > 0\}$, which is $1/2$ by symmetry.

Answer (score 3):

Let $r$ be an irrational real number. For real $x>0$, let $U_x$ be a random variable (r.v.) uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,x]$, and then let
$$C_x:=\cos rU_x+2\cos U_x.$$ Then the problem can be restated as follows: Is it true that
\begin{equation*}
    P(C_x>0)\to1/2\,\text{?} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
Everywhere here, the limits are taken for $x\to\infty$.

The answer to this question is yes. Indeed,
for each $(k,n)\in\{0,1,\dots\}^2$,
\begin{align*}
    &E\cos^k rU_x\,\cos^n U_x \\
    &=2^{-k-n}\,\frac1x\,\int_0^x du\,(e^{iru}+e^{-iru})^k \,(e^{iu}+e^{-iu})^n \\ 
    &=2^{-k-n}\sum_{p=0}^k\sum_{q=0}^n\binom kp\binom nq
    \frac1x\,\int_0^x du\,
    \exp\{iu[(2p-k)r+2q-n]\} \\ 
    &\to2^{-k-n}\sum_{p=0}^k\sum_{q=0}^n\binom kp\binom nq
    1(2p=k,2q=n),   
\end{align*}
since $r$ is irrational. So,
\begin{align*}
    &E\cos^k rU_x\,\cos^n U_x\to m_k m_n,   
\end{align*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    m_k:=1(k\text{ is even})2^{-k}\binom k{k/2}=E\cos^k U_{2\pi}. 
\end{equation*}
So, by dominated convergence, for the joint characteristic function (c.f.) $f_{r,x}$ of the pair $(\cos rU_x,\cos U_x)$ of r.v's and all real $s,t$ we have
\begin{align*}
    f_{r,x}(s,t)&=E\exp\{i(s\cos rU_x+t\cos U_x)\} \\ 
    &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n!}\,E(s\cos rU_x+t\cos U_x)^n \\ 
    &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n!}\,
    \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk s^k t^{n-k}E\cos^k rU_x\,\cos^{n-k} U_x \\ 
    &\to\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n!}\,
    \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk s^k t^{n-k}m_k m_{n-k} \\ 
    &=h(s)h(t),
\end{align*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    h(s):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{i^k s^k m_k}{k!}=E\exp\{is\cos U_{2\pi}\},  
\end{equation*}
so that $h$ is the c.f. of the (symmetric absolutely continuous) r.v. $\cos U_{2\pi}$.

So, the pair $(\cos rU_x,\cos U_x)$ of r.v's converges in distribution to a pair $(A,B)$ of independent copies of the r.v. $\cos U_{2\pi}$. So, for any real $b$, the r.v. $\cos rU_x+b\cos U_x$ converges in distribution to the symmetric absolutely continuous r.v. $A+bB$.

Thus, (1) follows.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.