# Sum of variables uniformly distributed on a circle: a cyclic property

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

Consider a random walk starting at the origin in the plane, walking $n$ steps in independent uniformly random directions with step lengths $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, and observing the distance from the origin. Let $b \mapsto W(b;a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ be the cumulative distribution function of this distance.

More formally, if $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b$ are positive real numbers, let $W(b;a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ be the probability that $\|a_1 U_1 + \cdots + a_n U_n\| < b$, where $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ are independent and uniformly distributed on the unit circle.

Can we prove directly that
$$
W(a_0;a_1,\ldots,a_n) + W(a_1;a_2,\ldots,a_n,a_0) + \cdots + W(a_n;a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}) = 1\ ?
$$

Can we interpret these $W$'s as the probabilities of $n+1$ disjoint and exhaustive events?  Can we give a higher-dimensional generalization?

This relaton is proved in Hermann Weyl's 1938 paper “Mean Motion” (*Amer. J. Math.* **60** (1938) 889–896), but only incidentally while proving something different (see [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278996/precise-form-of-the-mean-motion-theorem)), and without much commentary.

It may be useful that using the Hankel transform, $W(b;a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ can be expressed as $b \int_0^\infty J_1(bt) J_0(a_1 t) \cdots J_0(a_n t)\,dt$.

Comment: For $n=2$, $W(a;b,c)$ is one minus the probability that a random direction can be realized in a line from vertex $A$ to a point on side $BC$ in an an $a-b-c$ triangle.